# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, linker-errors

I know there's a lot of question like this one, but no one of those answers help me to solve my problem. What problem? Well,  when linking, after compiling my project I receive this:

> fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib'

I'm using CodeBlocks under Windows 8 64-bit. Compiling with the Visual C++ 2003 Toolkit compiler, which I have installed under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual C++ 2003 Toolkit` and using a lot functions from the Windows API, which I also have installed under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits`).

Searching on the internet I found some solutions like to link this library (`MSVCRT.lib`) under my project settings, but I definitely don't have that file. This is a project (the one in which I'm receiving this error) that I was working on about 15 days ago, and now I want to resume its development. I compiled and linked this project a lot of times, and I never got this linker error, I don't know why now I just can't link it.

Some solutions say I need to install VS.NET so the `MSVCRT.lib` file will be there, but I never had that installed and I was able to compile and link my project!

Any ideas on how can I solve this without installing VS.NET (also, I don't know if this is going to work)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 2 years, I finally found the solution in my case.

In CodeBlocks, under *Project* > *Build Options* > *Compiler Flags*, remove **Multi-threaded DLL Runtime Library [/MD]** and rebuild.

Comment: similar to Visual Studio, make sure to switch from ".exe" to ".dll"

Answer (score 1):

What just did it for me, was to delete the .sdf and .suo files.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this using Visual Studio 2017. After trial and error, I discovered that if I put an empty or blank value in the Linker --> Input section, it would give me the error about LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib'. Eventually I figured out that I should leave this value there instead.

On the Visual Studio project, right-Clicking on the project item in the Solution explorer panel (not the Solution itself, which is the topmost item), then select Properties. From there do the following:

*Linker --> Input* :  **%(AdditionalDependencies)**

This additional information might be helpful, if you got into the situation the same way I did. I was trying to compile with external .lib files. Previously I had a value in this input section like: *$(ProjectDir)lib; %(AdditionalDependencies)* but this lead to other problems and eventually I moved that value into:

*VC++ Directories --> Library Directories* : **$(ProjectDir)lib; $(LibraryPath)**

Note the $(LibraryPath) value will include extra values such as inherited from parents. My folder project contained a folder called 'lib' which is why I had the first value there before the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this -> [Integrating Microsoft Visual Toolkit 2003 with Code::Blocks IDE](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Integrating_Microsoft_Visual_Toolkit_2003_with_Code%3a%3aBlocks_IDE)

From there

> If the project you are compiling complains that it cannot find
>   "msvcrt.lib" then download the .NET 1.1 SDK and add to the END of the
>   Directories->Linker tab:
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Vc7\lib

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Give me some minutes to install and configure and I'll tell you if it works :-).